# CSS border in div does not fit to height of the content

Tags: html, css

I have created a CSS DIV with BORDER property to fit 100% height of the window and content. It works fine when the content is less than the window height. But, If the content is more than the window height, border still fits to window height only.

The code I used is given bellow:

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 520px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid blue !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #eee inset;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="form"></div>
```

Border corner snapshot is given below

[image: CSS Div Border]

Comment: why adding the code 3 times?

Comment: By mistake. Can't able to remove.

Comment: you are probably looking for a min-height instead of height

Comment: @TemaniAfif It works fine. I opened new incognito window and tried. Now works fine. Thank you.

Comment: note that the answer you accepted is wrong .. better add your own answer with the full working code and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **does work** with `min-height`.
Your problem was that you set a height onto `body` tag which was limiting the size of your `form` only the content was overflowing your box.

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 520px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid blue !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #eee inset;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem ipsoum<br>lorem 
</div>
```

Comment: make the code full page to see it's not working. `min-height: 100%;` is completely useless in this case

Comment: okay true. then we need to use 100vh or as I used 95 so you cant still see the border @TemaniAfif

Comment: now @TemaniAfif i got what u meant but you have to add some more values...